# Accessing Calendar control through Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2005, calendar

I have a asp.net calendar control, say Calendar1, in invisible state (visible = false ). How can I set visible to true using javascript when i press a client side button so that there is no postback done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit for this - http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx

The standard ASP.NET calendar control isn't designed for good client implementations, it posts waaaaaaaaay to much!